# The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'net.tcp'. parameter name: via

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, http, nettcpbinding

Hi i am having an issue with a wpf app connecting to a wcf service. the service has a netTcpBinding and uses an http scheme and and if i try to connect to it using the netTcpBinding i get the error
The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'net.tcp'. parameter name: via

Here is the web config

```
<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTcpBindingConfig" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered"
      transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" 
      maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">

      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192"
      maxBytesPerRead="4096"
      maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />

      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"
        protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
```

end point

```
<endpoint address="http://FinanceIccWS_5_0/IccService.svc"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConfig"
            contract="Gatherers.ICCService.ICCService" name="NetTcpBinding_ICCService" >
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="cssqaaspsvc@corp.fmglobal.com" />
            </identity>
```

and code theres is a catch method afterwards but didn't see it being relavent

```
 string address = "http://FinanceIccWS_5_0/IccService.svc?wsdl";

        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(address);
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding("netTcpBindingConfig");

        try
        {
            var proxy = new CCServiceClient(binding,endpointAddress);
            proxy.Open();
            test.TestDetails = proxy.State.ToString();             
            test.TestPassed = true;
            report.RetrievalStatus = RetrievalStatus.Succeeded;
            report.ApplicationStatus = ApplicationStatus.Passed;
        }
```

tried using protocol mapping but didn't seem to do anything

```
<protocolMapping>
    <add scheme="http" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConfig"/>
  </protocolMapping>
```

Comment: just add net.tcp endpoint to your server service and us it.

Comment: what if you don't have access to the service? Is it possible to tell a netTcpBinding on silverlight to expect a http scheme?

Comment: does the service provide MEX behaviour? if yes than try to use wcftestclient. Set the http endpoint and see what configuration generates the client.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<netTcpBinding>
<binding name="NetTcpBinding_ICCService" />
</netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
<endpoint address="net.tcp://FinanceIccWS_5_0/IccService.svc"
binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ICCService"
contract="ICCService" name="NetTcpBinding_ICCService">
<identity>
<userPrincipalName value="cssqaaspsvc@corp.fmglobal.com" />
</identity></endpoint></client></system.serviceModel>
</configuration>

Comment: end point address is net.tcp://FinanceIccWS_5_0/IccService.svc 
but the address i sentdinto wcftest client is http://FinanceIccWS_5_0/IccService.svc?wsdl
(sry for terrible layout of config with normal tabing it was considered to many characters)

Comment: so if you can invoke methods from the client, than use the same client configuration for your application

Comment: i did what you said but can't connect to the service with the net.tcp scheme. i can only connect to the service when it uses the http scheme(this was done through address bar and wcftestclient)

Comment: What about ProtocolMapping can i use that to tell my program to expect a http scheme though it's a netTcpBinding?